# News Data API or Feeds

Tags: api, rss, data-mining, feed

I would like to know if there is any news feeds/api that can be used for coding/datamining.
Skygrid for example gives live news feeds and if the news is good or bad, but it's all in flash and they don't seems to provide any rss other than their twitter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis) may have what you are looking for.

Programmable web is a good resource if you are looking for APIs/Services to play/build with.

### Some examples from the 'News API' category:

[**Digg**](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/digg) - Community driven news links and ratings

[**New York Times Newswire**](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/new-york-times-newswire) - All recent New York Times articles in summary

[**Reuters Spotlight**](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/reuters-spotlight) - Reuters.com content service

[**AmphetaRate**](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/amphetarate) - News Aggregator

[**News is Free**](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/newsisfree) - Online news aggregation

Answer (score 0):

FeedSyndicate.com is what we use for news, weather and stocks.  mid priced and great service